# Is the UK a republic?

Tags: united-kingdom, political-theory, republic

Obviously not in name, but in theory.

The UK is a representative democracy; its administration is elected by the people, who are recognised as [citizens, not subjects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_subject), enjoying the various freedoms (speech and so on) that that implies, [without an obligation of fealty](http://www.theguardian.com/media/2003/jun/27/theguardian.pressandpublishing). The unelected house [cannot prevent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament_Act_1911) the elected house from carrying out its will if it's determined enough, and the unelected monarch has limited executive powers [which can be nullified or taken away by Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_prerogative_in_the_United_Kingdom#Limitations), and effectively go unused. Parliament has also demonstrated a [low tolerance for dissent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_I_of_England#Execution) from the monarch in the past.

In other words all of the same basic freedoms and mechanisms seem to be present that would be in a parliamentary republic. So from a theoretical point of view, should the UK (and other "ceremonial monarchies", e.g. Japan) be classified with, and regarded as, republics (rather than linking them with true executive monarchies)? Are there any concrete implications to this?

Comment: Excellent question very well supported by sources. Eager to see an answer.

Comment: "Constitutional monarchy" nowadays seems to roughly mean "monarchical republic", honestly.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's a constitutional monarchy. The difference is that the the monarch still has some political powers even if it's mostly symbolic. In a real republic like the United States, France, Germany, etc, the parliament has all the political powers. The Republicans are trying to fool the people by saying that Obama is a monarch but they are wrong.

The political powers belong to the people in theory because many people argue that the judicial system, the media, the lobbies and other forces are taking powers away from the elected people but that is not in the constitution. Anyway, the judicial system applies the laws decided by the parliament not the other way around.

Comment: The legislature does _not_ have ultimate power in the US  -- the president is independently elected to a fixed term (he cannot be forced out except through impeachment) and has real power that doesn't derive from the legislature and which the legislature cannot take away. In systems where the parliament has all the power, the effective head of the executive branch serves at the pleasure of the parliament and cannot stay if they don't have the support of a majority of parliamentary support; in the US, the president's party need not have a majority in Congress.

Comment: @cpast yes and they are all elected by the population

Comment: Correct. But the _parliament_ does not have total power; parliament is not a synonym for the population.

Comment: -1: "In a real republic like the United States, France, Germany, etc, the parliament has all the powers". This is both strictly and broadly wrong.

Comment: "In a real republic like the USA [...] the parliment has all the powers." You don't understand the USA's governmental system. What does Obama have to do with the UK? "**The powers belong to the people in theory** because many people argue that the judicial system, the media, the lobbies and other forces are taking powers away from the elected people but that is not in the constitution." I thought it was the legislature that had the power? Also, what **isn't in the constitution**? (The power to take power away from the legislature?)

Comment: Oh I made a mistake, I should have been more precise: the parliament has all the political powers.

Comment: @user1873 An example is the lobbies influencing politicians in taking certain decisions.Lobbies do not really take the power away but they might mislead the elected politicians in making them believe that the lobby point of view is the right one even if the population disagree.

Comment: @Vincent Still wrong. Parliament is not a synonym for "the people"; it means the _legislature_, which has _less_ power in the US than in the UK (as the US president's power comes directly from the voters instead of from a majority in Congress, and he does not need approval from Congress to stay in office or do his job the way he feels it should be done, so a majority of the legislature cannot necessarily get its way).

Comment: There are also limits on how much Congress can do; the division of power between Congress and the president is broadly set out in the constitution, and Congress can't just pass a law to give themselves whatever power they want -- unlike the UK, the US has a written constitution which Congress _cannot_ override, and unelected (appointed, but then with life tenure) judges can and do strike down laws and executive actions for violating the constitution. Yes, judges apply the law, but Congress doesn't get to control the supreme law.

Comment: @cpast  So in the Us, the president is considered completely outside the parliament ? I guess it maker sense considering how he gets elected. When I said parliament I was referring to the elected officials in general, including the president.

Comment: @Vincent "Parliament" is never used to describe a US political institution, but generically it refers specifically to a legislature or other deliberative body. The US president is not a member of Congress; there's a list of members, and the president is not on that list (and is constitutionally barred from being on the list, as is everyone in the executive branch except the vice president [who technically is the president of the senate but doesn't really do anything for that, and a senator leads the senate in practice]).

Comment: @Vincent, still -1: "In a real republic like the United States, France, Germany, etc, the parliament has all the political powers". This is still both strictly and broadly wrong. The executive branch has tons of political power. The same can be said about the constitutional court.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão  If my answer is so bad, why don't you provide your own answer ? That would be more useful to the op.

Comment: @Vincent, because I don't know the answer. IMO all my comments here were constructive, and were intended to help *you*. Besides, your answer is not so bad. It is just that you have put the situation in such a simplified manner that the answer seems trivial, when it is not. My comments have been directed to those simplifications.